# Text wrapping, grid and star sizing

Tags: wpf, grid, textblock, word-wrap

I have some `text data` that I want to display in a `Grid`, with three columns, the middle column being twice as wide as the other two, taking up the full width of the grid. The `text` is long and needs to be wrapped. What I can't get to work (and from other queries here in the past, I see others have had similar problems) is getting word wrap and sizing to the grid to work. What I have is:

```
<Window.Resources>
  <local:DTData x:Key="dtData" />
</Window.Resources>

<StackPanel DataContext="{StaticResource dtData}">
  <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <Grid>
          <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
          </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <Border x:Name="a" Grid.Column="0" Margin="4"/>
          <TextBlock Margin="4" Grid.Column="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                     Text="{Binding A}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=a }" MinWidth="100"/>
          <Border x:Name="b" Grid.Column="1" Margin="4"/>
          <TextBlock Margin="4" Grid.Column="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                     Text="{Binding B}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=b }" MinWidth="100"/>
          <Border x:Name="c" Grid.Column="2" Margin="4"/>
          <TextBlock Margin="4" Grid.Column="2" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                     Text="{Binding C}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=b }" MinWidth="100"/>
        </Grid>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
  </ListBox>
</StackPanel>
```

This uses the `Border` trick from [WPF TextBox and Scroll behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/386039/wpf-textbox-and-scroll-behavior) to force text wrapping to work but the column's width is either the minimum width set or the longest word if greater.

Does anyone know of a way to force the columns to fit the width of the grid?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get WPF Grid columns defined with star to clip content?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25567474/how-do-i-get-wpf-grid-columns-defined-with-star-to-clip-content)

Answer (score 1):

You sure you wanna wrap the text? Or you goal is text trimming? I'm asking because when I type the following xaml in kaxaml, the text in the middle column is perfectly wrapped:

```
<Page
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
  <Grid>  
    <StackPanel>
  <ListBox ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Width="350">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <Grid>
          <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
          </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <TextBlock Margin="4" Grid.Column="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                     Text="Binding A"  MinWidth="100"/>
          <TextBlock Margin="4" Grid.Column="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                     Text=" Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco"  MinWidth="100"/>
          <TextBlock Margin="4" Grid.Column="2" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                     Text="Binding C" MinWidth="100"/>
        </Grid>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <TextBlock Text="" />
    <TextBlock Text=""/>
    <TextBlock Text=""/>
  </ListBox>
  </StackPanel>
  </Grid>
</Page>
```

If you want to trim the text, just set `TextWrapping="NoWrap"` and TextTrimming to `TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"` where needed.

There might be also that you haven't provided all the data, to reproduce the problem you are describing...

Comment: Thanks, but that meets two out of the three requirements: it wraps correctly and the columns expand to fir the width of the grid; but the column widths are variable with real data - yours align prettily because you're using the same data for each row.

What I haven't been able to do is get the text to wrap, the columns to fit the width of the listbox and the column widths to be consistent for each row.

Comment: Could you add a picture showing what you are trying to do? I still can't get it..

Comment: @amaca I think you may have been looking for [`SharedSizeGroup`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/how-to-share-sizing-properties-between-grids)