# Parent control ScrollViewer scrolling instead of child control ScrollViewer

Tags: c#, wpf, scroll, parent-child, scrollviewer

I have this:

```
<Window x:Class="ScrollTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Height="450"
        Width="525">
    <ScrollViewer ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <GroupBox Grid.Row="0"
                      Header="Stuff"
                      Height="200">
                <TextBlock Text="Lots of controls go here"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                           VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            </GroupBox>
            <TabControl Grid.Row="1">
                <TabItem Header="Main Tab">
                    <TextBox MinHeight="100"
                             HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                             VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                             HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
                             VerticalContentAlignment="Top"
                             ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                             ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                             AcceptsReturn="True" />
                </TabItem>
            </TabControl>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Window>
```

When I add too many rows into the `TextBox`, instead of the `ScrollViewer` of the `TextBox` being used, the box stretches and the outermost `ScrollViewer` is used. Can I prevent that without fixing the height of the `TextBox` or `TabControl`?

**Update:**

If I remove `MinHeight` on the `TextBox` and set `MaxLines` to 5, this is what I get:

[image: MinHeight removed and MaxLines set to 5]

If I added a 6th line, the scroll bars of the `TextBox`'s `ScrollViewer` are used, but they still remain centered vertically in the `TextBox` control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get close with this:

```
<Window x:Class="ScrollTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Width="525">
    <ScrollViewer ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                  x:Name="Base">
        <Grid Height="{Binding ElementName=Base, Path=ActualHeight, Mode=OneWay}"
              MinHeight="400">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <GroupBox Grid.Row="0"
                      Header="Stuff"
                      Height="200">
                <TextBlock Text="Lots of controls go here"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                           VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            </GroupBox>
            <TabControl Grid.Row="1">
                <TabItem Header="Main Tab">
                    <Grid x:Name="myInnerGrid">
                        <TextBox MinHeight="100"
                                 MaxHeight="{Binding ElementName=myInnerGrid, Path=ActualHeight, Mode=OneWay}"
                                 HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                 VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                 HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
                                 VerticalContentAlignment="Top"
                                 ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                                 ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                                 AcceptsReturn="True" />
                    </Grid>
                </TabItem>
            </TabControl>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Window>
```

Note the binding expression on height for the outside grid and on `MaxHeight` for the `TextBox`.

It's still not perfect in that you have to manually set the `MinHeight` that will trigger the  outer most scrollbar. It's probably as close as WPF will allow without writing a new grid control.

The idea was found here:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/7b4b0c88-6b8f-4f07-aa8b-8e7018762388

Answer (score 1):

Try looking at the [MaxLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.maxlines.aspx) and [MinLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.minlines.aspx) Properties.

From above link:

> Setting this property causes the text box to resize if the number of
>   visible lines exceeds the limit specified by MaxLines.   This property
>   applies only to visible lines, and does not constrain the actual
>   number of lines. Depending on its configuration, a text box may
>   contain additional non-visible lines that are accessible by scrolling.
>   If the Height property is explicitly set on a TextBox, the MaxLines
>   and MinLines property values are ignored.

Try Changing:

```
<TextBox MinHeight="100" 
         HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
         VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
         ...
```

to

```
<TextBox MinLines="5" 
         MaxLines="5"
         HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
         VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
```

Edit: Give this a try. It is setting the `VerticalContentAlignment` of the `TabItem`. This will keep the text box at the top of the `Tab`, I also set the maxlines to what your available area is able to hold if you resize your form you may want to adjust that number to use all of the available space.

```
<TabItem Header="Main Tab" VerticalContentAlignment="Top"  >
     <TextBox 
              ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"   
              ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" 
              MinLines="8"
              MaxLines="8"
              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"   
              VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
              HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"  
              VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"  
              AcceptsReturn="True" />
</TabItem>
```

---

Edit:

After looking into it further, the reason the scrollbars are not showing up on the `TextBox` is because the `TabControl` and the `TabItem` are resizing to the size of the `TextBox`. What needs to be done is to have a limiting height set either on the `TabControl`, `TabItem` or `TextBox` this will allow the `ScrollViewer` to work for the `TextBox`.

Comment: Good idea, but it had no affect.

Comment: @mbursill Did it limit the height at all? It should grow in number of lines up to the value that you set.

Comment: Nope. I tried setting the MaxLines to 5, and when I exceeded 5 lines, nothing different happened. When I reach 9 lines (if I haven't resized the window beyond the 450 of my example) the TextBox box starts to expand vertically, causing the outermost scroll-viewer to be vertically scrollable. The scroll bars of the TextBox are never used.

Comment: Try taking off the minHeight value to check. It states that if the Height property is explicitly set they are ignored.

Comment: Removing the MinHeight had a strange outcome. The TextBox remained at the * height (the height of the TabItem content, like I want), but the ScrollViewer contained inside the TextBox resized to be 5 lines and centered vertically. The text insertion point was in line with the ScrollViewer. I'll try and update the question with a screen shot.

Comment: Your updated code comes close to achieving what I would like, however, I want the TextBox height to size with the TabItem height. Min/Max lines constrains the TextBox height based on the line height. I could see that having having benefits for many layouts but not mine.

Comment: My question used a fixed height for the GroupBox as a proof of concept. In my "real" project the GroupBox contains a grid of many rows (roughly 10). Either way, wrapping the GroupBox with the ScrollViewer doesn't allow it to scroll. When the window is resized, or when many lines of text are typed, the height of the GroupBox never changes (nor should it), and therefore those scrollbars will never show.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the best solution to this is to use the `Border` trick outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/386039/wpf-textbox-and-scroll-behavior), applied both vertically and horizontally.

In the following example, a `ScrollViewer` contains a `TextBox`, where it is desired to have the `TextBox` fit all of the available space (vertically and horizontally), and have it scroll vertically before the parent `ScrollViewer`.  The `Border` `PlaceHolderBorder` manages the `Width` of the `TextBox`es as the parent window is resized.  The `Border` `DescriptionPlaceHolderBorder` manages the `Height` of the `Description` `TextBox` as the parent control is resized, and the `ScrollViewer` of the `TextBox` kicks in before the parent control.

It is important to have `Margin`s in the placeholder `Border`s.

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Background="{StaticResource ControlBackgroundBrush}">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="10"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="10"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Style="{DynamicResource LabelHeader}" Content="Company" />
        <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Style="{DynamicResource CompanyNameInput}" Content="{Binding CompanyNameLabel}" />
        <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Style="{DynamicResource DescriptionInput}" Content="{Binding DescriptionLabel}" />
        <Border Name="PlaceHolderBorder" Grid.Column="2" Margin="7"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding CompanyName}" MaxLength="255"/>
        <Border Name="DescriptionPlaceHolderBorder" Grid.Row="2" Margin="7"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Description}" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                 TextAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" AcceptsReturn="True" MinHeight="60"
                 Width="{Binding ElementName=PlaceHolderBorder, Path=ActualWidth}"
                 Height="{Binding ElementName=DescriptionPlaceHolderBorder, Path=ActualHeight}"
        />
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2" Margin="5">
            <Button Command="{Binding UpdateCommand}" Content="{Binding UpdateButtonLabel}"></Button>
            <Button Command="{Binding ResetCommand}" Content="{Binding ResetButtonLabel}"></Button>
            <Button Command="{Binding CloseConfirmCommand}" Content="{Binding CloseButtonLabel}"></Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```